# Javascript to check if todays date is after Tuesday at 6pm in current week

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datetime

I am trying to restrict users from seeing certain information on a landing page to only page by comparing if todays date is after Tuesday at 6pm within the current week.

I have been trying to setup this condition but Date/Time functions aren't my forte.

Using the below I am able to determine the days of the week, but it seems a little buggy in that if within a calendar week a new month starts, the logic resets to the next/previous month.

```
const today = new Date("2022-11-03 16:20:04");
const first = today.getDate() - today.getDay() + 1;
const tuesday = new Date(today.setDate(first + 1));
const wednesday = new Date(today.setDate(first + 2));
const thursday = new Date(today.setDate(first + 3));
const friday = new Date(today.setDate(first + 4));

console.log('tuesday: ' + tuesday);

const diffTime = Math.abs(tuesday - today);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 

console.log(diffDays + " days");
```

I figured by determining by how many days from monday, I could determine if this had been surpassed or not. Unfortunately, this also doesn't take into account time, only date as well.

Comment: What do you consider the first day of the week, Monday or Sunday?

Comment: In this case I would say Monday

Comment: In that case, if the day is Sunday, then `today.getDate() - today.getDay() + 1;` will return the following Monday, not the previous Monday. For that you need `today.getDate() - (today.getDay() || 7) + 1`. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code you have is that `setDate` **modifies** the `Date` object on which you call it, so all those calls to `today.setDate` are modifying the `today` date. To fix the existing code, first copy `today` and then modify the copied object:

```js
const today = new Date("2022-11-03 16:20:04");
const first = today.getDate() - today.getDay() + 1;
const tuesday = new Date(today);    // Copy today...
tuesday.setDate(first + 1);         // ...now modify
const wednesday = new Date(today);  // Copy today...
wednesday.setDate(first + 2);       // ..now modify
const thursday = new Date(today);   // ...
thursday.setDate(first + 3);
const friday = new Date(today);
friday.setDate(first + 4);

console.log("tuesday: " + tuesday);

const diffTime = Math.abs(tuesday - today);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

console.log(diffDays + " days");
```

*(Side note: It didn't used to be reliable to copy `Date` objects as shown above. If you need to support slightly out-of-date browsers, add `+` prior to `today` so you have `new Date(+today)`.)*

But it seems like there's a simpler way to check if a given date is after 6 p.m. on the current week's Tuesday:

```
function currentTuesdayAt6PM() {
    const today = new Date();
    const first = today.getDate() - today.getDay() + 1;
    const tuesday = new Date(today); // or `= new Date(+today);`
    tuesday.setDate(first + 1);
    tuesday.setHours(18, 0, 0, 0);
    return tuesday;
}

function isAfterCurrentTuesday(dt) {
    // Get the Tuesday for the current week at 6 p.m.
    const tuesday = currentTuesdayAt6PM();

    // Check date vs. Tuesday at 6 p.m.
    return dt > tuesday;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function currentTuesdayAt6PM() {
    const today = new Date();
    const first = today.getDate() - today.getDay() + 1;
    const tuesday = new Date(today); // or `= new Date(+today);`
    tuesday.setDate(first + 1);
    tuesday.setHours(18, 0, 0, 0);
    return tuesday;
}

function isAfterCurrentTuesday(dt) {
    // Get the Tuesday for the current week at 6 p.m.
    const tuesday = currentTuesdayAt6PM();

    // Check date vs. Tuesday at 6 p.m.
    return dt > tuesday;
}

function test(dt) {
    const result = isAfterCurrentTuesday(dt);
    const resultText = result ? "is >" : "is not >";
    console.log(`${dt.toLocaleString()} ${resultText} ${currentTuesdayAt6PM().toLocaleString()}`);
}

test(new Date("2022-11-03 16:20:04")); // After
test(new Date("2022-11-01 16:20:04")); // Before
test(new Date("2022-11-01 18:00:00")); // Before (we're doing >, not >=)
test(new Date("2022-11-01 18:20:04")); // After
test(new Date("2022-10-31 18:20:04")); // Before
```

Answer (score 0):

getDay() on Date gives number of day in a week starting 0(Sunday), 1(Monday), 2 (Tuesday).
getHours() gives hours.
Making sure we crossed 18hrs which is 6pm when day is 2 or day > 2.

```
const today = new Date();
const showInfo = (today.getDay() > 2  || today.getDay() === 2 && today.getHours() > 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

If Monday is the first day of the week, a general function to return a particular time on a particular day of the same week as the supplied date can help.

Then just compare the returned date to "now".

```js
function getDayAt(date = new Date(), day = 1, hour = 6) {
  let d = new Date(date);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - (d.getDay() || 7) + day);
  d.setHours(hour, 0, 0, 0);
  return d;
}

// Is now before Tuesday at 6 pm?
let now = new Date();
console.log('Now is before 6 pm Tuesday: ' + 
             (now < getDayAt(now, 2, 18)));
```